# LINQ query the most recent records

Tags: c#, linq

How to modify this query to be able to select the 5 most recent records sorted by title?

```
IEnumerable<Story> recentStories = 
            (from s in stories 
             orderby s.Date descending 
             select s).Take(5);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<Story> recentStories = 
            (from s in stories 
             orderby s.Date descending 
             select s).Take(5).OrderBy(s => s.Title);
```

Comment: Actually order by date then by title and only then take 5 would be more accurate when breaking ties.